# Pyspark RDD "list index out of range" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, rdd

I have RDD in this form:

```
[[['a'],['b,c,d','e,f,g']],[['h'],['i,j,k','l,m,n']]]
```

What I've wanted to achieve:

```
[['a ,b,c,d', 'a ,e,f,g'], ['h ,i,j,k', 'h ,l,m,n']]
```

What I did:

```
def pass_row(line):
  new_line = []
  key = ''.join(line[0])
  for el in line[1]:
    el = key +' ,'+ el
    new_line.append(el)
  return new_line

rdd.map(pass_row)
```

It works for smaller samples of data. However, I am getting `list index out of range` on line `for el in line[1]:` when I try to run it on my whole dataset...

Basically I have one key (lets say `['a']`) for ~100 different sets of values in `['b,c,d','e,f,g']`. My ultimate goal is to have it as spark dataframe in form of rows:

```
col1 col2 col3 col 4
a     b    c    d
a     e    f    g
h     i    j    k
h     l    m    n
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Apparently you have a recored which have one element instead of two. So, you'vw got an error for `line[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems more related to your data than your function (which seems to be correct, although a bit overcomplicated), and it looks like you applied it to a line that didn't have a `line[1]`.

Could you make sure that the number of elements of `line` is constant in your actual dataset, for example with :

```
def pass_row(line):
    assert len(line) == 2
    return [ "%s, %s" % (''.join(line[0]), el) for el in line[1]]
```

That being said, for your actual goal, you probably should stop dealing with strings from that point and directly get your data as a 2D-array, for example with :

```
def pass_row(line):
    return [line[0] + el.split(',') for el in line[1]]

>>> a = [[['a'],['b,c,d','e,f,g']],[['h'],['i,j,k','l,m,n']]]
>>> b = [ pass_row(i) for i in a ]
>>> b
[[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'e', 'f', 'g']], [['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ['h', 'l', 'm', 'n']]]
```

Warning here, you can't directly feed a DataFrame with that solution, as each group of prefix-generated lines is still nested in its own list (it's only a "list of 2D-arrays").

For example, using sum function, that you could easily transpose in a reduce step :

```
>>> sum(b, [])
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ['h', 'l', 'm', 'n']]
```

Your solution would thus need 3 steps :

- map your dataset with `pass_row` as you do
- reduce the result with `sum` built-in function, applied to the initial accumulator `[]`
- feed the result to a Spark DataFrame

In plain Python, the following one-liner would do the job

```
>>> fn = lambda ls : sum([ [ i[0] + el.split(',') for el in i[1]] for i in ls ], [])
>>> fn([[['a'],['b,c,d','e,f,g']],[['h'],['i,j,k','l,m,n']]])
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'], ['h', 'l', 'm', 'n']]
```